# Como convertir un dato de una fila en una columna?

Tags: pandas

Buenas como puedo convertir 'precio' en una columna como 'quote', deseo que en el dataframe solo esté el símbolo y el precio, pero este se encuentra dentro de 'USD', que a su vez está dentro de 'quote'

Código:

```
import apikey
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
headers = {
'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY' : apikey.key,
'Accepts' : 'application/json'
}
params = {
'start' : '001',
'limit' : '5000',
'convert' : 'USD'
  }
url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
json = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json() 
coins=json['data']
m=pd.DataFrame(coins)
z=m[['symbol','quote']]
ls=[]
for x in coins:
      ls.append(x['symbol'],)
      ls.append(float((x['quote']['USD']['price'])))



   
if x['quote']['USD']['percent_change_1h'] < -50:
        print(x['symbol'], x['quote']['USD']['price'], x['quote']['USD']['percent_change_1h'])   
   print(z)
```

Resultado:

```
                ***symbol                                              quote

   0            BTC  {'USD': {'price': 56641.105034525295, 'volume_...

   1            ETH  {'USD': {'price': 3458.956601395487, 'volume_2...

   2            ADA  {'USD': {'price': 2.09932017019545, 'volume_24...

   3           USDT  {'USD': {'price': 1.00042557257418, 'volume_24...

   4            BNB  {'USD': {'price': 405.04792262992294, 'volume_...***
```

Como pueden ver precio está dentro de 'USD', deseo que 'price' quede como columna así como está quote, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si pudieras poner un enlace a un fichero json como el que recibes de esa API. O mejor, un extracto de ese fichero como parte de la pregunta. De ese modo otros usuarios pueden hacer pruebas para dar con la solución, la cual depende de la estructura de ese JSON.

Comment: Así entrega los datos la api no tiene que ver el json, solo necesito saber como se puede hacer eso, puesto que independiente lo que se le haga al json la api entrega de ese modo los datos.

Comment: Lamento insistir... Ya sé que la API te devuelve los datos en JSON, pero es la estructura interna de ese JSON la que es necesario conocer para extraer correctamente la información que pides y poder dejarla en una columna, por eso te pedía una muestra del mismo. Naturalmente que el json sí que tiene que ver en la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

### Un ejemplo reproducible

Aunque el OP no ha suministrado un ejemplo del JSON de respuesta, he podido encontrar uno en la [documentación de la API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest) que se está intentando consultar. Reproduzco a continuación un ejemplo de ese JSON para que la respuesta sea reproducible. No obstante lo pego como una única línea para que no ocupe demasiado.

```py
json_response = '{"data": [{"id": 1,"name": "Bitcoin","symbol": "BTC","slug": "bitcoin","cmc_rank": 5,"num_market_pairs": 500,"circulating_supply": 16950100,"total_supply": 16950100,"max_supply": 21000000,"last_updated": "2018-06-02T22:51:28.209Z","date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z","tags": ["mineable"],"platform": null,"quote": {"USD": {"price": 9283.92,"volume_24h": 7155680000,"volume_change_24h": -0.152774,"percent_change_1h": -0.152774,"percent_change_24h": 0.518894,"percent_change_7d": 0.986573,"market_cap": 852164659250.2758,"market_cap_dominance": 51,"fully_diluted_market_cap": 952835089431.14,"last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"},"BTC": {"price": 1,"volume_24h": 772012,"volume_change_24h": 0,"percent_change_1h": 0,"percent_change_24h": 0,"percent_change_7d": 0,"market_cap": 17024600,"market_cap_dominance": 12,"fully_diluted_market_cap": 952835089431.14,"last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"}}},{"id": 1027,"name": "Ethereum","symbol": "ETH","slug": "ethereum","num_market_pairs": 6360,"circulating_supply": 16950100,"total_supply": 16950100,"max_supply": 21000000,"last_updated": "2018-06-02T22:51:28.209Z","date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z","tags": ["mineable"],"platform": null,"quote": {"USD": {"price": 1283.92,"volume_24h": 7155680000,"volume_change_24h": -0.152774,"percent_change_1h": -0.152774,"percent_change_24h": 0.518894,"percent_change_7d": 0.986573,"market_cap": 158055024432,"market_cap_dominance": 51,"fully_diluted_market_cap": 952835089431.14,"last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"},"ETH": {"price": 1,"volume_24h": 772012,"volume_change_24h": -0.152774,"percent_change_1h": 0,"percent_change_24h": 0,"percent_change_7d": 0,"market_cap": 17024600,"market_cap_dominance": 12,"fully_diluted_market_cap": 952835089431.14,"last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"}}}],"status": {"timestamp": "2018-06-02T22:51:28.209Z","error_code": 0,"error_message": "","elapsed": 10,"credit_count": 1}}'
```

Supongamos que este JSON ha sido recibido en respuesta a una petición con `requests`. En lugar de esa petición, para que la respuesta sea reproducible, usaré `json.loads()` para cargar la cadena anterior en un diccionario Python:

```py
import json
data = json.loads(json_response)
```

A partir de aquí se puede reproducir el problema que plantea el OP, que básicamente es que si se intenta convertir esos datos en un dataframe así:

```py
coins=data['data']
m=pd.DataFrame(coins)
z=m[['symbol','quote']]
```

Se obiene en `z` un dataframe que contiene diccionarios anidados dentro de una columna:

```py
  symbol                                              quote
0    BTC  {'USD': {'price': 9283.92, 'volume_24h': 71556...
1    ETH  {'USD': {'price': 1283.92, 'volume_24h': 71556...
```

### Una solución

Si el dataframe se crea de esta otra forma:

```py
m = pd.json_normalize(data["data"])
```

el resultado es que todos los diccionarios internos se "desempaquetan" dando lugar a multitud de columnas nuevas:

```html
     id      name  ... quote.ETH.fully_diluted_market_cap    quote.ETH.last_updated
0     1   Bitcoin  ...                                NaN                       NaN
1  1027  Ethereum  ...                       9.528351e+11  2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z
```

En concreto, por ejemplo, se tienen nombres de columna como `quote.USD.price` que contiene el precio convertido a USD, o `quote.USD.percent_change_1h`, etc. Estos eran nombres de las claves en los subdiccionarios.

Podemos extraer sólo las columnas de interés, y renombrarlas. Por ejemplo:

```py
x = m[["symbol", "quote.USD.price", "quote.USD.percent_change_1h"]]
x.columns=["symbol", "price", "percent_change_1h"]
```

y en `x` tendríamos ya el dataframe con la información buscada:

```html
  symbol    price  percent_change_1h
0    BTC  9283.92          -0.152774
1    ETH  1283.92          -0.152774
```

Comment: Amigo te agradezco mucho, la verdad no entendía bien lo del json porque soy novato en el asunto y ese código para leer la api lo vi en un video de youtube, muchas gracias!!!